# Mapkit with multi annotation (callout), mapping the next view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit, mkmapview

Wanted some help with a problem with mapkit I am facing. Should be a silly problem or I have missed out something while going through the mapkit framework.

Here is the senario.
I am placing multiple annotation on the map when the user performs some search like pizza.
Added button for the right annotation view, on click which opens a next detail view. The problem is how to send some information to the next view, for example I add index to annotations while creating them, now I want to access this information from annotation, and pass it to the next view via the selector set on the button.

I have checked all the mapkit delicate, but don't find a one where I can map this information with the next view and annotation.

Hope I have not confused you guys in my question. Please let me know I will reframe it.

Thaking in advance.

Comment: i am also creating an annotation pin as u did .on the click of my annotation pi i need to pass some values to my next class.but i got stuck in between .Could you please help me or provide some sample code to pass values on the click on annotation pin to next class

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you create the `UIButton` for the annotation, set the `tag` property (tag is an `NSInteger` property of `UIView`) to an id or array index that identifies the relevant object.  You can then retrieve that tag value from the `sender` parameter to your selector.

---

**Edit**: here's some sample code.

You create your annotation view and associate the button in your delegate's -mapView:viewForAnnotation: method:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    // Boilerplate pin annotation code
    MKPinAnnotationView *pin = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [self.map dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier: @"restMap"];
    if (pin == nil) {
        pin = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation: annotation reuseIdentifier: @"restMap"] autorelease];
    } else {
        pin.annotation = annotation;
    }
    pin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed
    pin.canShowCallout = YES;
    pin.animatesDrop = NO;

    // now we'll add the right callout button
    UIButton *detailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

    // customize this line to fit the structure of your code.  basically
    // you just need to find an integer value that matches your object in some way:
    // its index in your array of MKAnnotation items, or an id of some sort, etc
    // 
    // here I'll assume you have an annotation array that is a property of the current
    // class and we just want to store the index of this annotation.
    NSInteger annotationValue = [self.annotations indexOfObject:annotation];

    // set the tag property of the button to the index
    detailButton.tag = annotationValue;

    // tell the button what to do when it gets touched
    [detailButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetailView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    pin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = detailButton;
    return pin;
```

}

Then in your action method, you'll unpack the value from `tag` and use it to display the right detail:

```
-(IBAction)showDetailView:(UIView*)sender {
    // get the tag value from the sender
    NSInteger selectedIndex = sender.tag;
    MyAnnotationObject *selectedObject = [self.annotations objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];

    // now you know which detail view you want to show; the code that follows
    // depends on the structure of your app, but probably looks like:
    MyDetailViewController *detailView = [[MyDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName...];
    detailView.detailObject = selectedObject;

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
    [detailView release];
}
```

Comment: can u plz paste a sample, u r approach looks confusing to me

Comment: Oops, forgot to add the button to the pin.

Comment: Although could you please explain the `NSInteger annotationValue = [self.annArray indexOfObject:annotation];` line. This line crashes the app when I use my array of annotations. 

Is that what you meant? `annArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:ann1,ann2,ann3,ann4,nil];[mapView addAnnotations:annArray];` So I would use annArray. Would I need any extra data to the annotation object?

Comment: are you storing `annArray` in an instance variable?  The line you are asking about identifies which annotation you're producing a view for so that you can retrieve it later in `showDetailView`.  What does the console show after your app crashes?

Comment: Yes annArray is an instance variable, which is setup in viewDidLoad where it is added to the map view `[mapView addAnnotations:annArray]` 
Strangely, if I even try and trace the contents of annArray inside the `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` method, it crashes. Something is definatelty up.
The console says nothing cleverly.

Comment: Sounds like you're over-releasing annArray somewhere.  I suggest you post a question and show your code.

Answer (score 1):

In the Annotation view, is it possible to grab,say, the Title or Subtitle or any other information you used while creating pins? What i am looking to do is have a certain image popup in the annotation based on one of those variables.

```
#import "MapPin.h"

@implementation MapPin


@synthesize coordinate;
@synthesize title;
@synthesize subtitle;
@synthesize indexnumber;
@synthesize imageFile;

-(id)initWithCoordinates:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location
               placeName: placeName
             description:description
                indexnum:indexnum
            imageFileLoc:imageFileLoc{

    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        imageFile=imageFileLoc;
        [imageFile retain];
        indexnumber=indexnum;
        [indexnumber retain];
        coordinate = location;
        title = placeName;
        [title retain];
        subtitle = description;
        [subtitle retain];
    }
    return self;

}



-(void)addAnnotations {

    // Normally read the data for these from the file system or a Web service
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = {35.9077803, -79.0454936};
    MapPin *pin = [[MapPin alloc]initWithCoordinates:coordinate
                                          placeName:@"Keenan Stadium"
                                        description:@"Tar Heel Football"
                                            indexnum:@"1"
                                        imageFileLoc:@"owl.jpg"];
    [self.map addAnnotation:pin];
```

Comment: Please place a new, separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

You can implement these methods:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotation:(MKAnnotationView *)view;
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotation:(MKAnnotationView *)view;
```